# Qt Invalid json file

Tags: android, c++, json, qt

When I start the Android-Debug mode this error appears:

```
Invalid json file: C:/Qt/Projekt/android-libProjekt.so-deployment-settings.json
```

I have read that I have to change the Qt building path but it always the same error...

---

android-libProjekt.so-deployment-settings.json:

```
{
   "description": "This file is generated by qmake to be read by androiddeployqt and should not be modified by hand.",
   "qt": "C:\\Qt\\5.2.1\\android_armv5",
   "sdk": "C:/Users/Sür/Desktop/Android2",
   "ndk": "C:\\Users\\Sür\\Desktop\\android-ndk-r9d-windows-x86_64\\android-ndk-r9d",
   "toolchain-prefix": "arm-linux-androideabi",
   "tool-prefix": "arm-linux-androideabi",
   "toolchain-version": "4.8",
   "ndk-host": "windows-x86_64",
   "target-architecture": "armeabi",
   "application-binary": "C:/Qt/Projekt/libProjekt.so"
}
```

Comment: So, you have tried to change the default long path to something shorter and that did not fix the issue either?

Comment: Maybe an ecoding issue? I'd try with paths without umlaut (/Sür).

Comment: @Tr4in: I have the same issue. Did you get solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

In your JSON file, the path separator characters are different in the various paths, sometimes "`/`", sometimes "`\\`":

```
"qt": "C:\\Qt\\5.2.1\\android_armv5",
"sdk": "C:/Users/Sür/Desktop/Android2",
"ndk": "C:\\Users\\Sür\\Desktop\\android-ndk-r9d-windows-x86_64\\android-ndk-r9d",
...
"application-binary": "C:/Qt/Projekt/libProjekt.so"
```

Probably only one of these styles is correct. The fact that the complaint is about "Invalid json file" and not a missing value etc. would also point into this direction – a parsing error.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your projects tab, and changed the build directory to something shorter. That solved the problem for me at least.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was caused by non-English characters in the project path. My project was in a subfolder of a folder called `Sällskapsspel` (with an `ä`), so I renamed it to `Sallskapsspel` and the problem went away. So it seems like in your case it's the `ü` in `Sür` that's causing the problem.